# Export images along with data to excel from html table

Tags: javascript, image, export, export-to-excel

I am using [table Export plugin](http://ngiriraj.com/pages/htmltable_export/demo.php) to export a html table to excel. I also included a column with images as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/cLxfemx0/1/) as

```
    <tr>
        <td>Chinna</td>
        <td>1,363,480,000</td>
        <td>March 24, 2014</td>
        <td>19.1</td>
         <td><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/CekuQ.jpg" width='60'  height='60'/></td>
    </tr>
```

and exporting as

```
<a href="#" onClick="$('#customers').tableExport({type:'excel',escape:'false'});">export</a>
```

If I export this table to excel, the images are not showing. So how can I export that images too along with data.

Comment: this works for PC excel, but breaks on Excel for OSX